# How to display `geom_boxplot` and `geom_dotplot` spaced in ggplot2 when plot both at same time?

Tags: r, ggplot2, graphics

I am working on a project and trying to reproduce following plot.

[image]

Here is my attempt.

```
test<-data.frame(
  x=factor(rep(1:3, each=20)),
  y=runif(60)
)
p<-ggplot(test, aes(x=x, y=y,fill=x)) +
  geom_boxplot(width=0.2) +
  geom_dotplot(binaxis = "y")
p
```

But boxplot and dotplot are crowded together in my attempt. Any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can nudge the position of geoms by using `position = position_nudge(...)`. You can use this to offset the boxplot and dotplot in opposite directions. Example below:

```r
library(ggplot2)
test<-data.frame(
  x=factor(rep(1:3, each=20)),
  y=runif(60)
)
ggplot(test, aes(x=x, y=y,fill=x)) +
  geom_boxplot(width=0.2, position = position_nudge(x = -0.1)) +
  geom_dotplot(binaxis = "y", position = position_nudge(x = 0.1))
#> `stat_bindot()` using `bins = 30`. Pick better value with `binwidth`.
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-04-05 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

Answer (score 3):

I would use the `position_nudge(x = 0, y = 0)` function. This allows you to translate elements of a plot in x and y. The function can be used as the position argument in the `geom_xxxx()` functions. Such as by using `geom_boxplot(..., position = position_nudge(x = -0.1))` which translates the boxplots 0.1 to the left.

```r
library(tidyverse)

test<-data.frame(
  x=factor(rep(1:3, each=20)),
  y=runif(60)
)
p<-ggplot(test, aes(x=x, y=y,fill=x)) +
  #Translate left
  geom_boxplot(width=0.2, position = position_nudge(-0.1)) +
  #Translate right
  geom_dotplot(binaxis = "y", width = 0.2, position = position_nudge(x = 0.1))
p
#> `stat_bindot()` using `bins = 30`. Pick better value with `binwidth`.
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-04-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: Thanks so much, @Joel Kandiah. This indeed solves the problem.